# How can I ensure that my Axon Saga is notified of events which match the associationProperty?

Tags: saga, axon

I have a project which I am developing with Axon, but my Saga is not properly executing.

My Saga contains lines similar to this:

```
@StartSaga
@SagaEventHandler(associationProperty = "uuid")
public void handle(FirstEvent event) { 
    System.out.println("Processing FirstEvent for uuid=" + event.getUuid());
    associateWith("uuid", event.getUuid().toString());
    initialiseWorkflow(event.getUuid(), Status.CREATED) ;
} 

@SagaEventHandler(associationProperty = "uuid")
public void handle(SecondEvent event) { 
    System.out.println("Processing SecondEvent for uuid=" + event.getUuid());
    this.processStep(STEP_2,event.getUuid());
}
```

The First event is triggering a start saga, and also triggering the initialiseWorkflow tasks (which correctly creates a set of additional steps.) 
However, when the SecondEvent arrives (with same UUID associationProperty value as FirstEvent,) the saga does not pick up that second event.

I have tried specifically including the following line to enhance the association, but that also did not work:

```
associateWith("uuid", event.getUuid().toString());
```

Ironically, I have a test case, using the axon testing framework which works correctly, and this is similar to:

```
@Test
public void testSecondEvent() {  
     fixture.givenAggregate(uuid).published(new FirstEvent(uuid))
     .whenAggregate(uuid).publishes(new SecondEvent(uuid))
     .expectDispatchedCommandsMatching(exactSequenceOf(
             new CompleteTaskCommandMatcher("SecondEvent"))); 
}
```

The problem occurs in my end to end tests, which I am putting commands directly into the CommandGateway, and checking the results directly in the repository.

I have double checked that the AnnotatedSagaManager is being used, and it is.

Does anyone have any ideas on what could be wrong, or have I misunderstood how Sagas should work ?

EDIT: 
A few more updates:

1) I noticed that I needed to use toString() when directly associating the UUID, so I tried making the value into a string for the event - no progress.

2) I tried printing out the associated values, and I have seen that the direct association line is not required (the uuid is associated during the start saga process)

3) I tried putting @StartSaga on the secondEvent, and this reached the code for "Processing SecondEvent ... " but in a new saga.

More understanding, but no solution yet !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the cause of the problem...

I based my configuration on the Mongo profile for the AxonTrader sample app. 
However, the AxonTrader persistence-infrastructure-context.xml (shown next) contains a flaw:

```
<beans profile="mongodb">
    <bean id="mongoSpringTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
        <constructor-arg name="mongo" ref="mongo"/>
        <constructor-arg name="databaseName" value="axontrader"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.axonframework.eventstore.mongo.DefaultMongoTemplate">
        <constructor-arg index="0" ref="mongo"/>
        <constructor-arg index="1" value="axontrader"/>
        <constructor-arg index="2" value="domainevents"/>
        <constructor-arg index="3" value="snapshotevents"/>
        <constructor-arg index="4">
            <null/>
        </constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg index="5">
            <null/>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <bean id="mongoSagaTemplate" class="org.axonframework.saga.repository.mongo.DefaultMongoTemplate">
        <constructor-arg index="0" ref="mongo"/>
        <constructor-arg index="1" value="axontrader"/>
        <constructor-arg index="2" value="snapshotevents"/>
        <constructor-arg index="3">
            <null/>
        </constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg index="4">
            <null/>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <mongo:mongo id="mongo" host="127.0.0.1" port="27017"/>
</beans>
```

As you can see from the snippet above the eventStore and sagaRepository are both using "snapshotevents" as their parameter. However, the snapshot events is relevant to the eventStore only, and appears to cause a conflict when combined with the sagaRepository.

When I change this value to "sagas" for the sagaRepository, then everything falls properly into place !